# Why is my Edge not opening local file properly?

Tags: pdf, browser, microsoft-edge

I want to open local html and pdf files with Edge. It worked perfectly on my old laptop. But my new laptop cannot open them properly.

This is what happens when I drag the file:

[image: How I want to open it]

This is what happens when I double click the file:

[image: How it actually opens]

This is the full file name:

```
file:///C:/Users/xingy/OneDrive/Documents/six%20sigma/Grand%20content%20table/Grand%20Table%20for%20editing%203-2.htm
```

It seems Edge splits the full file name by space or % into different tags. It happens to all the local files when I try to open them with Edge. Is this a setting issue? What didn't I see it on my old laptop?

Comment: I could see that path in the address bar does not contain the file extension. Try to add **.htm** after the path will help you open the file properly. Further, try to set the Edge browser as the default app to open .htm files using **openwith** option from the context menu. See whether it helps to fix the issue.

Comment: I would like to confirm with you whether adding the .htm extension help you open the local HTML file? Let me know if you need further suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

If the file name contains a double space, thats what is causing the problem. Edge/Chrome registers both spaces as a single space. Take out the extra space or change the name of the file and that should resolve the issue.